# Eclipse RCP App Breaks Restart Behavior

Tags: eclipse-rcp, restart, launcher, equinox

My RCP app doesn't restart the workbench when I select `Restart` or `Switch Workspace`. I thought that maybe something was wrong in my RCP Application code, but then I made an installable feature with my plug-ins, minus the application plug-in, and that breaks the restart behavior of the eclipse IDE into which I install my feature.

So something in my code is breaking the capability to restart the workbench, and I can't figure out what that can be. I'm certainly not setting the system property "eclipse.exitcode", which is apparently what `IDEApplication` looks for when the workbench exits. I even tried explicitly setting this property value to 24, which seems to be the value that eclipse uses to signal a workbench restart. Still the IDE refuses to restart after I've installed my plug-ins.

I know this is an open-ended question, but I've looked through all my code and I just don't see anything I'm doing that could possibly break the restart behavior. Does anyone have any ideas as to what I might look for.

Comment: What are you using for the `IApplication`? If it is your code you need to handle these exit codes correctly.

Comment: That's the reason for testing my application as an installable feature. I launch the Eclipse IDE and install my plug-ins minus the plug-in that contains my custom IApplication implementation, through an update site I created.  Then I restart the IDE, with eclipse.application still set to org.eclipse.ui.ide.workbench. But the restart behavior is now broken, even using the Eclipse IApplication implementation (IDEApplication I believe).

Comment: By removing plug-ins one at a time, I narrowed it down to this. I have a plug-in that contributes an OSGI service, and the very act of contributing a service seems to break the restart behavior. I modified my service implementation class to have only stub methods which do nothing. When that service implementation is contributed, the restart behavior breaks. I'm using declarative services. Component declaration is in next comment.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<scr:component xmlns:scr="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/scr/v1.1.0" name="CmdLib Service">
   <service>
      <provide interface="my.package.CmdLib"/>
   </service>
   <implementation class="my.package.CmdLibImpl"/>
</scr:component>
As I mentioned above, CmdLibImpl has only stub methods that do nothing. With this declaration, and Service-Component: OSGI-INF/cmdlib_component.xml in MANIFEST.MF, restart behavior breaks.

Comment: Eclipse itself uses services like this (`org.eclipse.equinox.event` for example) so it can't just be that.

Comment: Agreed. Turning off lazy loading made it work if I also remove the code that invokes the service. It fails again when I re-instate the code that invokes the service. So DS isn't the problem; it's something downstream that is invoking the service.